# Add PHP variables to Mandrill template

Tags: php, email, mandrill

I just made the switch from the PHP mail function to Mandrill, but Mandrill sees the PHP in the email as HTML and prints the variables like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to add PHP to the HTML template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can use PHP with Mandrill, but you can use placeholders for custom content. Please take a look at the section of this [page](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694868-Getting-Started-with-Templates) titled "Create dynamic content (placeholders for custom content)"

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks a million Daniel. I'm not sure I would have found that without you - I was looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

Definity you can use PHP variable with template,same issue i was facing,

by using below statement,you can pass PHP code

```
<div mc:edit="main_content"></div>
```

Your code will be look like that

```
<div mc:edit="main_content">
  $title=$occasion

</div>
```